# how to redirect every url from a website to a new website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

I have setup a redirect in IIS 6.0 from a website to another web site via IIS Manager(using the option `Redirect to, The exact URL entered above, in the Home Directory tab`) . It works fine. e.g. if some one types `http://www.oldsite.com` its redirected to `http://www.newsite.com/landingpage.aspx` but there is a problem when a user types in  `http://www.oldsite.com/someoldpage.aspx` its redirecting to `http://www.newsite.com/landingpage.aspx/someoldpage.aspx` instead of `http://www.newsite.com/landingpage.aspx` Any ideas how to fix this redirect

[image]

Comment: Please share your redirect code.

Comment: You can find the old IIS 6.0 redirect reference here: https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx. You probably need to set the `$S` variable.

Comment: @Oluwafemi this is done via IIS manager. I have now added a screenshot